# How to use inverse operator in vectorization of a for loop?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, inverse

X with dimensions of k x n x n

Y with dimensions of m x n

Then,

```
for ii = 1:k

Z(ii,:,:) = Y/squeeze(X(ii,:,:));

end
```

I don't know how to vectorize this for loop. When k is large the computation becomes costly. I feel like there should be a way to handle the inverse without the for loop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you pre-allocating Z? I don't think the loop is the performance issue here, except if you are not pre allocating.

Comment: How big are k and n?

Comment: The indexing operations like `X(ii,:,:)` might be slow, they copy the data. Try swapping the dimensions so you can use `X(:,:,ii)` and `Z(:,:,ii)`, which indexes consecutive memory. Maybe it improves the performance.

Comment: @rinkert Z is pre-allocated on its original version.

Comment: Use `Symbolic Math Toolbox`, check [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/224361-simultaneously-inverting-many-matrices)

Comment: @Adam I ended up solving the problem some other way, but this was useful. Thanks!!